# Specify jest test files directory in React-typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I wanted only to test file is located in the specific tests directory that outside src.

Simple example:

```
simple-app

 1.src
 2.tests
```

jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  verbose: true,
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  snapshotSerializers: ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>src/setupEnzyme.ts"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"}
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I specified my test command in package.json via:

```
  "test:local": "jest ./tests/local.test.ts",
```

I have tried many time but it is not working. Any helps would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

In jest config, you should remove src path, if you want to test ouside src directory.

Here is the example:
It should be look like that `roots: ['<rootDir>/'],`. I assumed it would be work.